# ¿Cuales son los pasos para instalar mysql en red?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, .net, servidor, localhost

Tengo un software hecho en .Net que ya esta instalado en un computador, junto con su respectiva base de datos local de mysql. Necesito instalar el mismo software de .Net en otro computador pero que acceda a la misma base de datos.
Ambos computadores estan conectados por wifi en una red Lan.

Comment: debes de apuntar a la ip en este caso como servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practicamente todos los sistemas de base de datos (MySql, MS-SQL, Oracle) funcionan como servicios, por lo que la implementacion del software en el segundo computador necesita un cambio en la cadena de conexion, de forma que apunte al primer computador.

Probablemente tu cadena de conexion apunta al servidor "localhost" o direccion "127.0.0.1".

Consigue la direccion IP del computador original, ponla como el nombre de servidor en la cadena de conexion, compila e instala en tu nuevo computador.

PRIMERA NOTA MUY IMPORTANTE:
Hacer esto no es recomendable para un desarrollo de software profesional, pero si estas experimentando o aprendiendo, o vas a hacer un trabajo local para ti, no habria mayor problema.
Lo correcto es que toda informacion por red pase por un servicio web, y que sea el servicio quien interactue con la base de datos.

SEGUNDA NOTA IMPORTANTE:
Para verificar si va a funcionar antes de que instalar tu software, puedes instalar MySQL Workbench en el segundo comp[utador y tratar de conectarte a la base de datos del primer computador. Con esto veririficaras que no haya cortafuegos ni nada que impida la conexion.

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema de hacerlo así? ¿hay problemas de seguridad? (Teniendo en cuenta que es un desarrollo para una tienda con dos puntos de pago)

Comment: Hay muchas ventajas en tener un servicio web, pero eso es tema para hacer otra pregunta en Stack Overflow. No alcanzaria este espacio para una explicacion completa.